# How to set a default or add a Foreign Key in ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**Context:**

- using Django 3.0.4.

I have two models

- `UserProfil` a arbitrary UserModel automatically created by registering
- `UserList` more or less a simple list of lists

Every registered User can create a new `UserList` entry in my model by giving a `UserList.name` in a form. If i put `UserList.name` and `UserList.profile` in the form my template generates the inputs and i can enter every value. it works so far.

But it´s obvious Users should not allowed to choose the `UserList.profile` relation in the template, because if so, they could create a new list entry related to other users. so i need to set the value to the current user.

My approach to save this relation was what u see in `SingleListForm.save` of my forms.py
Unfortunately nothing is saving when i am entering a value for `UserList.name` in my Template Input. 
It only shows `my form_invalid`message: *"Error something went wrong"*.

additionally i also tried to removed the `profiler`field from `fields:`in my`SingleListForm` and tried to save. but then i get the message

```
The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: profil_userlist.profiler_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

### **Question**

How to set a default or add a Foreign Key in ModelForm?

---

**models.py**

---

```
class UserProfil(models.Model):
    # --- head
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    # --- relation   
    user_con = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # -- link 
    userlink = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # --- body
    userinfo = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="about you")

#---receiver:  if new AUTH.user -> UserProfil create UserProfil entry 
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, dispatch_uid="new_profil")
def create_new_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfil.objects.create(user_con=instance)

class UserList(models.Model):
    # --- head
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    uvlink = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # --- relation  
    profiler = models.ForeignKey('UserProfil', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # -- body
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True, help_text="List Name")
    listname_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    # -- # Sluggenerator
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.listname_slug:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.listname_slug = slugify(self.name)

        super(UserList, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # -- # END

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse("store:mylist", kwargs={"listname_slug": self.listname_slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name[:60])
```

---

**views.py**

---

```
class SingleListCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name ="store/list/single_list_create.html"
    form_class = SingleListForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('store:single_list_create_confirmed')
    queryset = UserList.objects.all()

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        msg = "Error something went wrong"
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, message=msg))
```

---

**forms.py**

---

```
class SingleListForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserList
        fields = [
            'name',
            'profiler',    
        ]

        labels  = {
        'name':'List Name'
        }


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SingleListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].help_text

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # --- get the form data, before saving all
        formData = super().save(commit)

        # --- get relation of current user
        setUserProfil = self.request.user.userprofil.id

        # alternative
        # setUserProfil = self.request.user.userprofil

        # -- set relation
        formData.profiler_set.add(setUserProfil)

        # alternative
        # formData.profiler.add(setUserProfil)

        return formData
```

---

### Solution 1

related to **@Yellowduck** thanks!

**forms.py**

```
class SingleListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserList
        fields = [
            'name', 
        ]

        labels  = {
        'name':'List Name'
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SingleListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].help_text
```

**views.py**

```
class SingleListCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name ="store/list/single_list_create.html"
    form_class = SingleListForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('store:single_list_create_confirmed')



    queryset = UserList.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profiler = self.request.user.userprofil
        form.instance.profiler = profiler
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

### **Solution 2**

I also found a solution by set `ìnitial` into the form and a `hidden_input` in the Template

**forms.py**

```
class SingleListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserList
        fields = [
            'name',
            'profiler',    
        ]

        labels  = {
        'name':'List Name'
        }

        widgets = {
            'profiler': forms.HiddenInput()
            }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SingleListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].help_text
```

**views.py**

```
class SingleListCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name ="store/list/single_list_create.html"
    form_class = SingleListForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('store:single_list_create_confirmed')
    queryset = UserList.objects.all()

    def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = super(SingleListCreateView, self).get_initial(**kwargs)
        initial['profiler'] = self.request.user.userprofil
        initial['name'] = "hello"
        return initial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the `profiler` field in your `SingleListForm` as you don't want user to select the profile freely. The form will then only contains one field `name` which is exactly what you want the user to fill in.

In your `CreateView`, override `form_valid` to add the desired `Userprofil` object:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    profiler = *your_query_to_get_profiler*
    form.instance.profiler = profiler
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: For better answering i created a response under "related to @Yellowduck"  above...

Comment: did you remove the `profiler` field in your form? also you should override `form_valid `instead of `form_invalid`